# My program causes segmentation faults in a Windows DLL - how can I debug it?

Tags: c++, debugging, crash, segmentation-fault

So I've written this relatively large (~6000 LOC) Qt application, which I use with Windows 7, and I'm getting these strange segmentation faults. Most of the time everything works as I expect it to, but sometimes, I get a segmentation fault in ole32.dll which is part of Windows. The disassembly looks like this:

```
Function: ole32!CoAddRefServerProcess
0x7601c98a  <+0x02e3>         or     %cl,0x37890446(%ecx)
0x7601c990  <+0x02e9>         call   0x760326a6 <ole32!ObjectStublessClient15+2849>
0x7601c995  <+0x02ee>         xor    %eax,%eax
0x7601c997  <+0x02f0>         pop    %esi
0x7601c998  <+0x02f1>         pop    %edi
0x7601c999  <+0x02f2>         pop    %ebx
0x7601c99a  <+0x02f3>         pop    %ebp
0x7601c99b  <+0x02f4>         ret    $0x4
0x7601c99e  <+0x02f7>         mov    (%eax),%ecx
0x7601c9a0  <+0x02f9>         push   %eax
0x7601c9a1  <+0x02fa>         call   *0x8(%ecx)
0x7601c9a4  <+0x02fd>         jmp    0x7604a6d9 <ole32!CoRevokeClassObject+16608>
0x7601c9a9  <+0x0302>         test   $0x2000000,%eax
0x7601c9ae  <+0x0307>         jne    0x76025dc1 <ole32!StgOpenStorage+5555>
0x7601c9b4  <+0x030d>         jmp    0x7604a715 <ole32!CoRevokeClassObject+16668>
```

The fault always happens in the same dll function at the same place (the first mov command). There is no particular time or place in the application when the fault will occur, but it's more likely to strike when the program is collecting or saving data (it seems to be stable when it's doing nothing - I've left it running over night without crashing).

I'm kind of puzzled by this, since the segmentation happens in a piece of code I didn't write, and even though bugs in Windows are not unheard of, I guess it's more likely that my program is somehow messing up the memory that this dll uses and hence causes the problem. Can anyone suggest how to find the code that's really causing the problem?